# The header row wraps to the next row but the data doesn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

You're probably going to hate me for this, sorry ...

In the data explorer the result grid wraps the header row with the columnames on the next row if the result set has an insane amount of columns. As a result of this you can't see the data in that column and due to this wrap you can't fully see the last row.

This is what is seen on the top:

[image]

And this is the bottom:

[image]

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266704) that demonstrates that effect.

As a work-around we should limit the number of columns in our resultset.

Can this be put on the list of things to fix somewhere in the future?

Answer (score 3):

What, the hardcoded maximum of 10000 pixels* in SlickGrid isn't enough for you?

Unfortunately, the SlickGrid maintainer had to put aside upkeep of the project early last year, but luckily it turns out we hadn't actually updated SlickGrid in even longer, and the newer versions include a fix for this.

Now [updated for all your ridiculous column needs](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/57), pending a pull and redeploy.

<sub>*Which only applies to the header, for whatever reason</sub>

Comment: Yes, I'm beyond limits... thanks!